# How can I make a JSON object, the output will be like this?

Tags: java, json

I am very new to json, How can I make a JSON object the structure (output string)would be like this?  I am using the org.json library.

Is this a json array contians json array?

I have input like this:

```
111(root)
----222(child of 111)
--------333(child of 222)
--------444(child of 222)
----123(child of 111)
--------456(child of 123)
--------456(child of 123)
```

How can I make a json the output would be like blow,

```
{
"name": "flare",
"children": [
    {
        "name": "analytics",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "cluster",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "AgglomerativeCluster",
                        "value": 3938
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "CommunityStructure",
                        "value": 3812
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "name": "graph",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "BetweennessCentrality",
                        "value": 3534
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "LinkDistance",
                        "value": 5731
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "name": "animate",
        "children": [
            {
                "name": "Easing",
                "value": 17010
            },
            {
                "name": "FunctionSequence",
                "value": 5842
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change your dependency and use a library that allows Object mapping such as Jackson, or you can do the mapping by hand as follows:

```
private static JSONObject toJSONObject(String name, Object value) {
    JSONObject ret = new JSONObject();
    ret.put("name", name);
    if (value != null) {
        ret.put("value", value);
    }
    return ret;
}

public static JSONObject addChildren(JSONObject parent, JSONObject... children) {
    parent.put("children", Arrays.asList(children));
    return parent;
}

public static void main(String[] sargs) {
    JSONObject flare = toJSONObject("flare", null);
    addChildren(flare,
        addChildren(toJSONObject("analytics", null),
            addChildren(toJSONObject("cluster", null),
                toJSONObject("AgglomerativeCluster", 3938),
                toJSONObject("CommunityStructure", 3812)
            ),
            addChildren(toJSONObject("graph", null),
                toJSONObject("BetweennessCentrality", 3534),
                toJSONObject("LinkDistance", 5731)
            )
        ),
        addChildren(toJSONObject("animate", null),
            toJSONObject("Easing", 17010),
            toJSONObject("FunctionSequence", 5842)
        )
    );
    System.out.println(flare.toString());
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, but how can I retrieve value after I insert? I need to check if a child is already exist. like treemap. I have tried the  flare.getJSONObject("children"), this throw me error "JSONObject["children"] is not a JSONObject."

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I have found a way to retrieve the value with JSONObject tempObject = tempJSONArray.getJSONObject(i) tempObject.get("name").equals(name);

Answer (score 0):

You can simply have class like this.

```
public class Node {
     String name;
     List<Node> children;
     String value;
   }
```

Comment: Yes, I tried this with jackson lib, it throw me classnotfound exception. I added jackson-core-2.1.5.jar jackson-databind-2.1.5.jar, jackson-annotations-2.1.5.jar to path.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by ObjectMapper's pretty print.

```
public String pretty(Object object) throws JsonProcessingException {
  return OBJECT_MAPPER.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(object);
}
```

You may use my library for it.

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>json-utils</artifactId>
    <groupId>org.bitbucket.swattu</groupId>
    <version>1.0.16</version>
</dependency>

new JsonUtil().pretty(object);
```